# Menu bar still present after uninstall

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I have been using a Vodafone mobile broadband(modem) and decided to get rid of it then everything went wrong. I dragged the app and dropped it on to the trash but its menu bar is still there but inactive. I searched for multiple help to rectify the problem but still the menu bar was there. I used easy find to look for everything related to Vodafone and deleted it still the menu bar was there. Nothing in the PC has Vodafone related files except that its menu was present.

**Guys is there any way I could deal with this or is it a more larger problem than I thought.**

Comment: Not at a Mac, so can;t check exact steps, but look in `system preferences > login > startup items` and see if anything is listed.

Comment: @stuffe I found it in the startup and it finally worked. Put your solution in form of answer so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few places where items can get launched, and the most common place is in `System Preferences > Login > Startup Items`.  That's the goto place for most issues like this.

Removing the Application doesn't always remove all traces, especially if the App was installed by an installation script, rather than simply being dragged into your Applications folder in the first place.  Scripted installs often perform all sorts of background installs, such as kernel extensions, and helper apps that sit in the Menu Bar, and the startup items list is the common place to fire them up.

Answer (score 0):

When this app is installed, typically it also installs a folder in Applications named "Vodafone Utilities", that contains one item that is called "VMB Uninstall", which you can use to remove it altogether. This removes the startup and the icon on the menu.